# Access Variable of Activity from BaseAdapter

Tags: java, android, baseadapter

I want to access a variable from an activity in a `BaseAdapter` class with whom I set the `ListView` of the activity.
But I always get this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Integer.toString()' on a null object reference
```

These are the relevant parts of my code:

```
public class GetAllEntrysListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Integer markerID;
PinboardActivity pinboard = new PinboardActivity();

public GetAllEntrysListViewAdapter(JSONArray jsonArray, Context context) {
    this.dataArray = jsonArray;
    this.context= context;
    //I want to get the markerID variable from pinboardActivity:
    markerID = pinboard.markerID;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}
//...
public Cursor getLikes(DbHelper dbh) {
    //The following line is the one the error occurs
    String args[] = {markerID.toString(), pos};
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because `markerID` is `null`.
Check your following line

```
//I want to get the markerID variable from pinboardActivity:
    markerID = pinboard.markerID;
```

Here the `pinboard.markerID` is returning a null object.

Comment: But in the pinboardActivity the variable is not null

Comment: You are creating a new instance of the activity! `PinboardActivity pinboard = new PinboardActivity();` creates a new empty activity and there `markerID` is null. Ideally you should never create a new instance of an Activity like this. Best way is to pass `markerID` in the constructor of the adapter.